# XML processing script only lists one element but there are multiple elements to list

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I put together a simple Python script to print out XML data for all package names that are associated with parent element attribute: `Security Advisory`.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('errata.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for security in root.findall("*[@type='Security Advisory']"):
    packages = security.find('packages')
    print(packages.text)
```

The XML data is located [here](https://cefs.b-cdn.net/6010e333a44911e24b5112e23acbb346ae15f7b7/errata.latest.xml)

However, the script only prints out the first package name but there are multiple package names.  How would I go about getting all the package names that fall under parent attribute: `Security Advisory`?

Comment: Maybe you find `findall` instead of `find`?

Comment: @larsks Changed this: **packages = security.findall('packages')** Received this error: **print(packages.text) AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'**

Comment: That's correct. Because now you're getting a *list* instead of a single item, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below (it seems to work)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

import requests

r = requests.get('https://cefs.b-cdn.net/6010e333a44911e24b5112e23acbb346ae15f7b7/errata.latest.xml')
if r.status_code == 200:
    root = ET.fromstring(r.content)
    sec_elements = [e for e in root.findall("*[@type='Security Advisory']") if
                    e.find('os_release') is not None and int(e.find('os_release').text) > 6]
    for ele in sec_elements:
        packages = ele.findall('./packages')
        for p in packages:
            print(p.text)
```

Comment: Thank you for this!  This is much better since it pulls the XML directly.  Why did you use: **('./packages')** instead of: **('packages')**?

Comment: @alteredstate I think both should work the same so I dont have a good explanation for that...

Comment: Would it be possible to take this one step further and print out the package list based on the `'Security Advisory'` as well as the: `os_release` element text?  Here is a small sample of the XML:



`<CEBA-2020--0749>
<os_arch>i686</os_arch>
<os_arch>x86_64</os_arch>
<os_release>6</os_release>
<packages>nfs-utils-1.2.3-78.el6_10.2.i686.rpm</packages>
<packages>nfs-utils-1.2.3-78.el6_10.2.src.rpm</packages>
<packages>nfs-utils-1.2.3-78.el6_10.2.x86_64.rpm</packages>
</CEBA-2020--0749>`

Comment: What do you want to have? Do you want to find the packages if CEBA elements that their type is @type='Security Advisory' AND the os_release element has a specific value? Try to clarify.

Comment: Yes, exactly!  Print out package list based on **@type='Security Advisory'** (as we have done) and **os_release** > 6.

Comment: you mean `os_release > 6` ?

Comment: Both:  @type='Security Advisory' and os_release > 6 (greater than 6).

Comment: Really appreciate that!  This was my first attempt at something in Python so it's been challenging!  Is what you did between the [ ] for **sec_elements** considered a "multi-part variable"?  I would like to read more about what you did so was searching for it in the manual.